# how to insert multiple rows in a table using different subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I have a couple of tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[prods](
    [IdProducto] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IdGrupo] [int] NULL,
    [IdCategoria] [int] NULL,
    [IdAlmacen] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Codigo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Nombre] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Descripcion] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Cantidad] [int] NULL,
    [Imagen] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [StockMin] [int] NULL,
    [StockMax] [int] NULL,
    [Ancho] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Alto] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Largo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Peso] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Volumen] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Color] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Material] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Presentacion] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [bitPrecioVentaUnico] [int] NULL,
    [PrecioCompra] [money] NULL,
    [DescuentoCompra] [float] NULL,
    [PrecioVenta] [money] NULL,
    [DescuentoVenta] [float] NULL,
    [Estado] [varchar](20) NULL
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[prodnuevos](
    [Codigo] [int] NULL,
    [itemid] [int] NULL,
    [Item] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Categoria] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Cantidad] [int] NULL,
    [Minima] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Costo] [money] NULL,
    [Valor] [money] NULL,
    [peso] [float] NULL,
    [unidades] [float] NULL
)
```

both tables are somewhat similar, both have a list of products, prodnuevos (which we could consider Spanish for New Products), has a more extended list than prods(Let's call it Products)

what I want to do is use a query that will insert all rows that are available in New Products that are not available in Products...

I have tried this long query

```
INSERT INTO prods (IdGrupo, IdAlmacen, Codigo, Nombre, Descripcion, Cantidad, Imagen, StockMin,StockMax, Ancho, Alto, Largo, Peso, Volumen, Color, Material, Presentacion, bitPrecioVentaUnico, PrecioCompra, DescuentoCompra, PrecioVenta, DescuentoVenta, Estado) 
VALUES (1, 'Ninguno', (Select prodnuevos.Codigo FROM prodnuevos LEFT JOIN prods ON prodnuevos.Item = prods.Nombre WHERE prods.Nombre IS NULL), (Select prodnuevos.Item FROM prodnuevos LEFT JOIN prods ON prodnuevos.Item = prods.Nombre WHERE prods.Nombre IS NULL), '', (Select prodnuevos.Cantidad FROM prodnuevos LEFT JOIN prods ON prodnuevos.Item = prods.Nombre WHERE prods.Nombre IS NULL), '', 0, 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Ninguno', 0, (Select prodnuevos.Costo FROM prodnuevos LEFT JOIN prods ON prodnuevos.Item = prods.Nombre WHERE prods.Nombre IS NULL), 0, 0, 0, 'Activo');
```

when I try this, I get the following error

> *Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.*

I wonder how can I use this query properly.

By the way, Is there also a way that I can use less subqueries instead of repeating it various times?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

You got the right idea, just approaching the problem the wrong way. You should first `SELECT` a result set that will get you the data that you wish to copy over, then prefix it with your `INSERT` like so:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (col1, col2)
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table2
```

You also don't need to include columns in your `INSERT ... VALUES` list that have a default and don't exist in your child table.